# Why is one of my files listed when checking out a new branch?

Tags: git

I created a new branch but just below the branch confirmation messsage I can see a Word doc that I happen to have in my repo listed with `D` in front of it. What does this mean? I've tried searching but it's very difficult to search for `D`!

```
$ git checkout -b estimated-time
Switched to a new branch 'estimated-time'
D       ~$W error messages.docx
```

Comment: I think it means the file has been deleted. What does `git status` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the file `~$W error messages.docx` (which is a temporary file created by microsoft word) was deleted (missing in your computer).

Probably someone has commited this file by mistake before (these temp files should never be on git - should be added to .gitignore)...

I believe you should push the file deletion and add the pattern to .gitignore to avoid temporary/binary files.